# Encryption and decryption with iOS and PHP

Tags: php, ios, encryption

I've got an iOS app, with some additional apps planned, that stored particular data for the user. I'm working on plans to write a PHP sync server under an Apache web server to allow users to create an account and synchronize data across multiple devices. I'm not set up with SSL at my web host, so I'm looking for a built-in method to encrypt/decrypt data during sync.

Encrypting/decrypting on the PHP end will be fairly simple, thanks to mcrypt. But I haven't yet found the best way to do encryption/decryption on the iOS side. I've found some people who have used open-source or custom encryption methods, but is there something in the Apple API that provides a straightforward way to encrypt/decrypt data?

Comment: Found what I needed in the CommonCrypto library: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/Security/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

So many problems with this I don't know where to start.

Device A (has changes to sync)
Webserver (you have this already)
Device B ( needs changes from A)
Device C (needs changes from A)

[1] Encryption changes depending on the content you are sending.

[2] Do you want the data to be encrypted from Device A to Device B and C?  Or is it enough that the data is encrypted from A to the Webserver?

If you need it to b encrypted end to end (A to B,C) then you need to use symetric encryption where the key is shared between all 3 devices and NOT the webserver.  If you want the data to only be encrypted up to the point of the webserver then you just should use SSL (it will be MUCH faster).

[3] How are you going to manage these encryption keys (assuming you aren't using SSL)?

Overall this doesn't sound remotely secure, encryption isn't something you just "turn on" or "Plug in" and end up with a secure environment.  Maybe you could tell us about what your overall goal here is.

Comment: I've worked out the overall encryption plan, just not sure which methods are available in iOS for encryption. The strategy I have. The server-side code will not be a problem. The iOS-side code is what I need help with, specifically just needing pointers to methods/classes/libraries that will allow me to code the implementation on the iOS end.

Comment: As for the strategy, I'm looking at end-to-end encryption. I've already got a plan for how to handle the unique encryption key between client and server. Implementation does not need ultra-tight security; data being sync'd is not particularly sensitive (no financial data, passwords, etc, just user notes and some other data related to app functionality). I want to make it difficult for anyone trying to pry. What I have in mind should keep things secure enough. SSL encryption would be the best solution, but as mentioned above, I don't have it and it's not worth the cost when my needs are basic.

Comment: On any shared server SSL can't be more than $5 a month.  If security is important than get a SSL cert.  If security isn't worth the $5 a month then the data isn't important and you don't need encryption.  It's these sorts of broken encryption systems which give people false confidence and lead to data breaches.

Comment: Heck, even cheap dreamhost has ssl for less than $5 a month.  http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Secure_Hosting#Costs_and_Requirements

Comment: I was looking at the cost of the certificate more than the private ip (though $5/mo has a way of adding up). I don't need users to be faced with a certificate warning every time they sync, something likely to happen with the free cert. A paid cert costs more in the $150 range.

Comment: Most shared host servers come with a certificate for that server already installed.  You DO NOT have to pay for your own certificate (it will say the hosting company's name) and users do NOT get any sort of prompt.